# firebase-messaging.js not found laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello everyone I am making an application using firebase for push notifications. This is my first project in firebase. The issue I am having is with the connection as when I run the project and click on the login button it gives me

> Notification permission granted

But after this it returns an error which is as follow.

> A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
>   firebase.js:24 Unable to get permission to notify. FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:8000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).
>       at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-messaging.js:1:44674

I don't know why it is happening as I can see my js file and all the code as well, here is my config files.

In my **firebase-messaging-sw.js** which is on root directory the code is

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
 'messagingSenderId': 'SenderID'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
console.log(messaging);

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
// Customize notification here
const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
const notificationOptions = {
body: 'Background Message body.',
icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
};

return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
 notificationOptions);
 });
```

And in my **firebase.js** file the code is as follow:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "API-KEY",
authDomain: "authDomain",
databaseURL: "DBURI",
projectId: "P-ID",
storageBucket: "SB",
messagingSenderId: "SenderID",
appId: "AppID",
measurementId: "MeasurementID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission().then(function () {
console.log("Notification permission granted");
return messaging.getToken();
}).then(function (token) {
console.log(token);
}).catch(function (err) {
console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
});

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
console.log(payload);
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it's working perfectly fine. Posting it for others who faces similar problem. The issue was in my **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file. I was initializing the firebase with **sender id** it was written in the documentation. I just initialized the firebase object with all the configuration values changing the initializing object solved my problem.