# FirebaseError:: We are unable to register the default service worker

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

**FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).**

*PS : I have *firebase-messaging-sw.js* in root folder( i.e /public )*

**firebase-messaging.js**

```
/*
Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries are not available in the service worker.
*/
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-messaging.js');

/*
Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the messagingSenderId.
* New configuration for app@pulseservice.com
*/
firebase.initializeApp({            
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        });

/*
Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background messages.
*/
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log(
        "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
        payload,
    );
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = "Background Message Title";
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: "Background Message body.",
        icon: "/itwonders-web-logo.png",
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(
        notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions,
    );
});
```

Comment: What do you get when you try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/firebase-messaging-sw.js` ?  Do you get the .js to download or do you get a `404` (as the message indicates)?  If a 404, you have an issue with the way your project is configured.  You'll need to provide a lot more information: technology(ies) being used, what the HTTP server is, etc.

Comment: While accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/firebase-messaging-sw.js I get the code of the file but if I run http://127.0.0.1:8000/firebase-messaging-sw it returns error 404

Comment: In your browser's Developer Tools >> Network tab, see which network request is returning a 404.  Would be good to know exactly what URL the browser thinks it is failing to reach

Comment: it says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I have added `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in root folder only which is public folder in Laravel

Comment: I think `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304861/firebase-messaging-js-not-found-laravel` is same problem but I didn't understand in the answer. ( Added the code of `firebase-messaging.js`)